# fdisk. What does the "free" partition mean?

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

I had two primary partitions (`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`). Then I created an extended partition to segment it into logical partitions.

After I had typed `fdisk /dev/sda` and `n` (add a new partition) the following message appeared.

> p primary (2 primary, 1 extended, 1 free)
>
> l logical (numbered from 5)

What does `1 free` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a traditional [Master boot record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), you only get four slots for primary or extended partitions. You already have two primary partitions, and one extended (in which you can create logical partitions). So there's only one slot left in the MBR for an additional primary partition.